# PUSHButton is completely redrawn with WM_DRAWITEM. It's not what I want

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to put several buttons in my GUI interface to simulate a kind of TabbedPane. When I click on a button, this button should change color and if we click on another button, the old button would become again with the standard background and property of Windows of my dlg file.

Here is my PUSHBUTTON created in my '*.dlg' file :

```
PUSHBUTTON " >", LOKPL_SELBESTPLAATS, 26, 110, 10, 12, BS_OWNERDRAW
```

I tried to redraw the button in order to get the old standard property of my button.

I catch the `WW_DRAWITEM` event to redraw my button but as I said, it doesn't work.

```
case WM_DRAWITEM:

 const DRAWITEMSTRUCT& dis = *(DRAWITEMSTRUCT*)lparam;
 if (dis.itemAction | ODA_FOCUS) {
    
    COLORREF ref = GetSysColor(COLOR_BTNHIGHLIGHT);

    SetDCBrushColor(dis.hDC, ref);

    SelectObject(dis.hDC, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));

    RoundRect(dis.hDC, dis.rcItem.left, dis.rcItem.top, dis.rcItem.right, dis.rcItem.bottom, 10, 12);
 }
```

On the screen, I get a white round button and not a rectangle. And the background color is not the standard color of a standard PUSHBUTTON in Win32.

[image]

Is there a method, a property to get old properties of my 'dlg' file or do I need to redraw my button?

Comment: C or C++? One typically doesn't program in more than one language at a time, so please only tag the one you're actually programming in.

Comment: It could be helpful if you add a picture.

Comment: It's done. I've added a picture with an arrow to show you the problem

Comment: Just so you know, `dis.itemAction | ODA_FOCUS` is always true.

Comment: And why is it surprising that you get a circle, when it looks like you told it to make the round part of the rectangle the whole rectangle?

Comment: And if you want a default pushbutton then why are you using owner draw?

Comment: With a pushbutton without the flag BS_OWNERDRAW, the event 'WW_DRAWITEM' was not trigerred.Why Don't I use a pushbutton without BS_OWNERDRAW ? Because with a simple pushbutton, I couldn't modify background color when I click on the button :(.

For the following condition 'dis.itemAction | ODA_FOCUS', what do you propose instead of ?

Comment: It's all or nothing. Draw the entire button, and handle all scenarios. Or let the system do it all.

Comment: How can I change the background color of a button when I click on this one ?

Comment: @user2274060 You can change button's background color either via own draw or subclass but you **can't only change background color**. As you already found that except the background color, other drawing work also need to do by yourself. This is by design.

Comment: @user2274060 A possible alternative is combining button and another control whose background color is easy to change like [Edit Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-edit-controls).